# How to make rows with overflow on in one loop

Tags: php, html, css

I need pictures to appear in multiple rows. The problem is I have to do it all in one big loop and with overflow:auto. Is there anyway for me to do this?
Here is the code:

```
<div class="horizontal2">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <?php for ($i=0; $i <60; $i++): ?>                             
                    {{ user:profile }}
                      <img class="picformatting" src="{{ profile_picture:image }}" />
                    {{ /user:profile }}                                   
                  <?php endfor;?>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

Here is the CSS (horizontal2):

```
.horizontal2{
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-left: 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried floating the images?

Comment: What is the css for the picformatting class? Try floating the images to the right and do a display: inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about :

```
<?php
$max_img = 10;
?>
<?php for ($i=0; $i <60; $i++): ?>
    {{ user:profile }}
        <img class="picformatting" src="{{ profile_picture:image }}" />
        <?php if(fmod($i, $max_img) == 0) echo "<br/>"; ?>
    {{ /user:profile }}                                   
<?php endfor;?>
```

of course, it's not in auto mode but can be a "solution" ...

Answer (score 1):

```
li#container {
   width:400px;
   height:auto;
}
li#container img {
   display:inline-block;
   width:37px;
   height:37px;
   margin:3px;
}
```

You can just use `display:inline-block` property. It will adjust so, if more than 10 images are in row then it will enforce it to another row.